# page renders correctly but gets refreshed many time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, backbone.js, frontend

I am using Backbone.js and I have four templates which display the 4 graphs. Everything is working fine but only issue is my page refreshes four times before all the graphs renders on the UI. The refresh of page happens real fast. the refresh icon of chrome flickers super fast before page/graph starts showing.

I am using `when then` of jquery to make sure my model gets completely fetched before view starts rendering. Also, I am calling `this.render()` four times for all the view models of graph. And that's obviously needed as I have four templates. Can someone guide me what could be issue.

```
first viewmodel:

 initialize: function() {
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
      this.render();
    }
```

same thing is  repeated for all four view models.

Actual View Model for one graph:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
  var firstSubViewModel = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#myChart-template').html()),
    /**
     * render function. Renders data onto graph.
     * @param none
     */
    render: function() {
      console.log("inside first sub view render");
      $(this.el).html(this.template());
      var ctx = $(this.el).find('#lineChart')[0];
      var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
          datasets: [{
            label: "This Year",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
            data: this.model.attributes.incThisYear
          }, {
            label: "Last Year",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(3, 88, 106, 0.70)",
            data: this.model.attributes.incLastYear
          }]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Income in $'
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    },

    initialize: function() {
      console.log("inside first sub view initialize");
      this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
      this.render();
    }
  });

  return firstSubViewModel;
});
```

Fiddler Screenshot:[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use `$(this.el)`, there is already `this.$el` shortcut. Same for `$(this.el).find('#lineChart')`, use `this.$('#lineChart')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a shot in the dark but I believe the issue lies in the fact that you add the even listener first (`this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`), then when you actually call `render()` it is detecting a change which in turn fires `render()` again. 
Just try flipping them:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.render(); // render it first
  this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
}
```